# Make a certificate for testing purposes but NOT self signed

Tags: windows, ssl

I want to have a certificate that has a different CA cert for it.

**Reason?** - For self signed certs, most browsers handle this as a invalid certificate. I know I can ignore those warnings but I just don't want to get them in the first place.

I tried googling how to create such a certificate but found so many sites where only a self signed certificate is created.

Therefore, how can such a certificate + CA certificate be generated and is there a better synonym for such a certificate pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need certificate signed by trusted CA there are two options:

1. You can get free [letstencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate.
   This certificate will work everywhere, not only your testing machine.
   To get such certificate you need to **own** (e.g. buy) some domain, so you can pass [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) ownership challenge.
   If you need to test local server, you can get certificate for subdomain (e.g. `local-test.example.com` is subdomain of `example.com`) and map that subdomain to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts`.
2. For purpose of local testing, certificate signed by self-signed **CA** can be sufficient.
   Google Chrome and most other applications will accepts such certificate **after** you [install/trust your self-signed CA](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-computer-trust-certificate-authority-57649.html) (some applications may require restart).
   There are some convenient tools written in go and js.